# Use other file than cdv-electron-main.js for ipc in cordova-electron

Tags: cordova, build, electron, ipc

It is possible to use other file than cdv-electron-main.js for IPC?

I am currently using cordova-electron for a project, and, to handle the electron main process, the document ation say to directly edit the file cdv-electron-main.js in pro/cordova/platforms/platform_www.

But this can be problematic because, if you delete the electron folder (with the command "cordova platform rm electron"), you delete also this file.

My question is, is it possible to use an other file for the ipc, and if yes, how can I do this ?

Link to the documentation : [Customizing the Electron's Main Process](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/12.x/guide/platforms/electron/index.html#how-to-support-nodejs-and-electron-apis)

*If it is necessary to customize the Electron's main process beyond the scope of the Electron's configuration settings, changes can be added directly to the cdv-electron-main.js file located in {PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/platform/electron/platform_www/. This is the application's main process.*